# Using webpack, threejs examples, and typescript?

Tags: typescript, three.js, webpack

I'm having a lot of trouble getting stuff in threejs's examples (like EffectComposer or Detector) to work with webpack and typescript.

First off the relevant `*.d.ts` files are all present and installed via `tsd`.  My problem is getting webpack to actually include files outside of the default threejs build (namely things in `examples/js/`).

With `three` installed from npm I can do something like

```
import THREE = require('three');
```

Which works fine but lacks any of the aforementioned goodies.  There are a few other threejs packages on npm that bundle plugins but I don't think they work with typescript (since `require('three-js')(['EffectComposer'])` is rejected by the typescript compiler.

Has anyone gotten something in this package (like postprocessing) to work with typescript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

```
$ npm install --save-dev exports-loader imports-loader
```

Then, to use something from `three/examples/js`, I do this:

```
const THREE = require('three');
// imports provides THREE to the OrbitControls example
// exports gets THREE.OrbitControls
THREE.OrbitControls = require('imports?THREE=three!exports?THREE.OrbitControls!../../node_modules\/three\/examples\/js\/controls\/OrbitControls');

// use THREE.OrbitControls ...
```

I think the right thing to do is use the `imports` and `exports` loaders [by config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#loaders-by-config) rather than embedding them in the require. I'll update this answer when I have an example.

Comment: This still works, though I omitted the `THREE.OrbitControls = ` bit. It would be nice to have this in `webpack.config` rather than in the code file, but I struggled to get that working.

Comment: Found a way to do it in the config file, see answer below.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to find a pretty clean way to set this up in `webpack.config.js`.

As per Dan's answer:

`$ npm install --save-dev imports-loader`

It turns out we don't actually need `exports-loader`, since the three.js examples add their constructors to the `THREE` object.

Then, in `webpack.config.js`, we can add a rule to add `var THREE = require('three');` to an imported module if the module's path resolves to anything containing `three/examples/js`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
    {
      test: /three\/examples\/js/,
      use: 'imports-loader?THREE=three'
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the example modules will find the THREE global when they expect it.

Then, to make importing examples a little less verbose:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'three-examples': path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/three/examples/js')
  },
  ...
},
```

This assumes that `webpack.config.js` is in the same directory as `node_modules`, adjust accordingly.

Now, we can use the example files like so:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import 'three-examples/controls/OrbitControls';
```

to import the module for its side-effects.

If you're using this with Typescript and/or Babel and are getting warnings about the example module not being found on `THREE`, you may find [this issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader/issues/68) on the `imports-loader` repository useful to reference.

Comment: Could you please provide the whole webpack config here, where to add the resolve part?

Comment: I have a bunch of extraneous details in mine, but following https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ it's in the top level of module.exports, alongside `module`

Comment: For me it only works with 'const THREE = require('three');'

Comment: It works, but that warning really bothers me - have you found a way around it?

Comment: @rpadovani I'm not sure which warning you're referring to. Do you mean the one referenced in Jokester's answer?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to bundle OrbitControls with (webpack v2 + ts-loader) and no other loaders.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.85.2",
    "@types/three": "^0.84.12",
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
},
```

entrypoint.ts:

```
import * as THREE from "three";

// OrbitControls.js expects a global THREE object
(window as any).THREE = THREE;

// NOTE: OrbitControls must be included with require:
// using "import" cause it to be executed before global THREE becomes available
require("three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls");

// ... code that uses THREE and THREE.OrbitControls
```

NOTE: webpack may warn like `"export 'OrbitControls' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'`, because `OrbitControls.js` is not a proper JS module. I suppose we can just ignore this warning.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer just the part of your question regarding TypeScript and ThreeJS integration within your IDE.

As you've seen, most of the components are hosted on the DefinitelyTyped archives. I do recommend stop using `tsd` and migrate to `typing`.

A basic `typings.json` that `typing` will consume is listed below. It gets the latest main ThreeJS and the effect composer library to be recognized by TypeScript. Note the commit hashtags will change as the `.tsd` evolves.

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "three": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/threejs/three.d.ts#c6c3d3e65dd2d7035428f9c7b371ec911ff28542",
    "three-projector": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/threejs/three-projector.d.ts#48f20e97bfaf70fc1a9537b38aed98e9749be0ae",
    "three-detector": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/threejs/three-effectcomposer.d.ts#48f20e97bfaf70fc1a9537b38aed98e9749be0ae",
    "three-effectscomposer": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/threejs/detector.d.ts#48f20e97bfaf70fc1a9537b38aed98e9749be0ae",
    "three-shaderpass": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/threejs/three-shaderpass.d.ts#ee05b1163d8da7f16719f08d52f70ab524f1003a"
  }
}
```

Attached is a snapshot of an IDE recognizing the public methods of the EffectsComposer. You may want to also experiment with different module loader capabilities of TypeScript.

[image: TypeScript within the IDE recognizes the ThreeJS libraries]