# unable to import THREE.js in es6

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, three.js, create-react-app

I'm trying to show a three.js scene inside a div using create react app. However, it throws an undefined THREE.

Tried

1. npm install --save three
2. import * as THREE from 'three'

But doesn't seem to work, it always throws THREE is not defined no-undef. Kindly have a look at my repo as well. https://github.com/priyakrishnadev/webglapp

Update:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.1.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-timeago": "3.4.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "three": "^0.88.0",
    "timeago-react": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you please also update your package.json in git repo ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I have updated the post.Kindly check it.Thank you.

Comment: Did you try import * as THREE from ‘three.js’  ?

Comment: @Radio Yes tried it, also tried setting timeout for objloader and mtl loader. However it comes down to throw an error saying THREE undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is that you are importing THREE as es6 modules, but then trying to include DDSLoader, MTLLoader and OBJLoader which are not in THREE and are not set up as modules (as they are in the /exmaples/js/ folder in three.js).

You need to use versions that are set up as modules. eg [three-obj-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-obj-loader).
There are a few of these, and some are set up differently from others, some even set up specifically for use with react, so you are going to have to look at how to implement the one you choose. Search for them on the npm site.

An example of using three-obj-loader can be seen as an [answer on this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695357/using-three-js-obj-loader-in-react).